# JS/VUE Replace Placeholders in Office Files

Tags: javascript, pdf, vuejs3

is there any way to replace placeholders in Word, Excel and PDF Files via Javascript?

So that someone can upload a template file (xlsx, word or pdf with placeholders) on your page and after fill up a form and click on submit, the template file get replaced by the values from the form.

As far as i see, there is no all-in-once solution for that, so you have to find and use multiple tools for the requirement. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, there's always a way... But not an easy way at all. PDF will be the easiest if you can use forms inside them, you can then use a pdf library to fill the form easily. For Word and Excel, microsoft provides SDK in C# not in nodejs. But you can still open the word file by unzipping it and then manipulating the raw XML to fit your needs. My team and I just finished a MVP for a SaaS tool that does just that, and this was in no means easy to accomodate for any word/excel template (user provided ones at least)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! We will discuss further steps intern with this information. Ive got the information that https://www.pdftron.com should do this, but i have no idea if this works. But thanks!!